# Joining acrylic and dowel with nut and bolt?

Tags: drilling

I'm planning to do this project that involves joining acrylic (1cm or 0.4inches thick) to a dowel that's 2.75cm (1 1/16inches) in diameter. I plan on joining the acrylic piece onto the dowel by cutting a hole in the acrylic (using a laser cutter) equal to the size of the hole I'll drill through the dowel, and join them together with a bolt and nut. Does this sound like an achievable thing that won't require enormous amount of time and effort (I'm kind of on a deadline?) Here's what it might look like:

[image]

Many thanks.

Comment: Not really sure what you're doing here.  Are these two separate views of the same piece?  The labels aren't particularly clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any major problems with that.  Drilling a two holes and running a bolt through them to hold them together is a pretty simple task.  Though drilling a large hole through a dowel can be tricky unless you have a drill press and clamp the dowel well.  They want to twist and roll.  But with the bare minimum you've given us, yes, it's possible and should be reasonable.  Leaving me with the questions of why? and what is this for?

Comment: The hole on the acrylic will be achieved via laser cutting

Answer (score 1):

It will work, but, there's always but, it also depends on the acrylic (whether it's extruded or cast). Cast is much more durable for the action you're trying to pull, and extruded is prone to cracking when drilled.

Comment: The hole on the acrylic will be achieved via laser cutting

Comment: Laser doesn't damage edges on Cast acrylic, but on extruded one you can see it's basically as drilled as it will leave small cracks and is prone to chip.

Answer (score 1):

That will work, but it won't be very durable. The problem is that the nut or bolt head which bears on the dowel will be making contact on a very small area and the stress may damage the contact area, leading to the bolt coming loose.

Answer (score 0):

Will the dowel be tightly secured to the acrylic with the bolt and nut, or is it designed so the down can spin on the bolt?  Are you going to use washers between the pieces?

If you're attempting to tighten the bolt with a nut I would worry about cracking the acrylic.

I think more information on what you're building would help immensely.